# Sender and event arguements in MS Access 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to have an event sender/args sent to a forms On Load event in MS Access 2010. Similar to vb.NET. Something similar to the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

This way my form could respond differently depending on who calls it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Openargs with [OpenForm](DoCmd.OpenForm Method) and that can pass the calling form.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs
```

In the Open event, you can then refer to

```
Me.OpenArgs
```

For example, if a form called MyFirst, I open a form:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  DoCmd.Openform "MySecond",,,,,"MyFirst"
End Sub
```

On MySecond form, I can say:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   MsgBox "This form opened by : " & Me.Openargs
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I'm getting the 2450 Form not found error. I'm not sure how to pass it correctly. I would assume, pass-by-reference rather than pass-by-value. Also, wouldn't Me.OpenArgs imply that OpenArgs is a control in the current form, rather than a form in it's own right? I would think it would be something like Me.ControlName=Forms!OpenArgs!ControlName

Comment: OpenArgs is a property of a form. I have added a note.